# Tipo de dato para IVA en MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Tengo un formulario donde ingreso IVA, quiero que en mi base de datos MySQL se almacene el mismo campo que se escribe en el formulario, es decir "0,19" que es el valor de IVA en este momento. He probado actualizando mi tipo de dato a decimal, así:

```
change_table :remisions do |t|
      t.change :iva, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
    end
```

En mi schema esta así:

```
t.decimal "iva", precisión: 10, scale: 2
```

He intentado con casi todos los datos numéricos que recibe MySQL: "int, float, double, bigint". Estuve investigando y la solución que encuentro es esa que estoy planteando, pero no me funciona, por eso recurro aquí, necesito que se almacene tal cual, ya que es para sacar el IVA a cada producto.
En mi base de datos solo se almacena el entero, en este caso solo el 0 o cuando pongo el punto se almacenan solo los que estan a la izquierda del punto, los de la derecha se pierden Ej: ingreso :"127.90" Almacena :"127".

Comment: Cuando guardas el 0.19 en una columna de tipo FLOAT(2,2) por ejemplo ¿cómo queda en la base de datos?

Comment: Ummm es cierto se me habia olvidado, en la base de datos se guarda solo el entero , es decir solo el "0", y cuando pongo punto solo se guardan los del punto hacia la izquierda

Comment: pues yo revisando este tema de la consola de mysql, te confirmo que al usar `DECIMAL(3, 2)` yalmacenando `0.19` y después haciendo un `SELECT` me muestra el mismo valor sin problema

Comment: Pero en la base de datos se almacena 0.19 ?  Lo intente y a mi no me da, me aparece simplemente 0

Comment: @STIVENARTEAGAESPITIA estas seguro que estas declarando el tipo de dato así?, de hacerlo desde la migración, ya revisaste en la documentación que tu sintaxis sea correcta?

Comment: Si, tal cual como esta el codigo, mi schema :   t.decimal "iva", precision: 10, scale: 2

Comment: Al parecer el problema está en el código (i.e. probablemente estás mandando el número sin decimales); ¿puedes compartir el código donde se genera el valor y donde se guarda?

Comment: @Gerry, no entiendo lo que quieres que ponga, el formulario esta creado con un scaffold, lo que yo pienso es que al principio yo lo defini cono integer pero ahora con una migracion lo modifique a decimal. Cuando edito mi campo a : "165454.12", en mi consola aparece UPDATE `atriremis` SET `iva` = 165454, `updated_at` = '2019-01-11 12:45:53' WHERE `atriremis`.`id` = 6. Como pueden ver el campo iva solo aparecen los de la izquierda, no entiendo porque se pierden los de la derecha pero aun asi aparece la coma.

Comment: El problema entonces sí viene desde el código, en algún lado estás perdiendo las decimales. Agrega a tu pregunta la vista, controlador y modelo relacionados, así podremos ver donde se pierden las decimales.

Comment: @Gerry Muchas gracias, efectivamente se estaban perdiendo, en mi schema estaba correctamente, pero verifique la estructura de mi db y estaba integer, lo cual lo modifique directamente en la base de datos ya que no fue actualizado por algun motivo, ya da perfecto, muchas gracias...